# converting uint8_t to NSString in RSA decryption

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I am trying to implement the RSA algorithm and i followed apple [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13).
But i am getting problem to convert uint8_t to NSData to NSString.

I have done this so far..These function defined in [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13)

```
-(void)test{
    [self generateKeyPairPlease];
    NSData *data = [self encryptWithPublicKey]; //All goes well until here
    [self decryptWithPrivateKey:data]; 

}
```

For encryption i did..

```
- (NSData *)encryptWithPublicKey
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    size_t cipherBufferSize;
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer;                     // 1

// [cipherBufferSize]
    const uint8_t dataToEncrypt[] = "the quick brown fox jumps "
                            "over the lazy dog\0"; // 2
    size_t dataLength = sizeof(dataToEncrypt)/sizeof(dataToEncrypt[0]);

    SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;                                 // 3

    NSData * publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier
             length:strlen((const char *)publicKeyIdentifier)]; // 4

    NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey =
                            [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // 5

    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
                                                                // 6

    status = SecItemCopyMatching
    ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKey); // 7

//  Allocate a buffer

    cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey);
    cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);

//  Error handling

    if (cipherBufferSize < sizeof(dataToEncrypt)) {
        // Ordinarily, you would split the data up into blocks
        // equal to cipherBufferSize, with the last block being
        // shorter. For simplicity, this example assumes that
        // the data is short enough to fit.
        printf("Could not decrypt.  Packet too large.\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Encrypt using the public.
    status = SecKeyEncrypt(    publicKey,
                                kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                                dataToEncrypt,
                                (size_t) dataLength,
                                cipherBuffer,
                                &cipherBufferSize
                                );                              // 8

//  Error handling
//  Store or transmit the encrypted text

    if (publicKey) CFRelease(publicKey);

    NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:dataLength];

    free(cipherBuffer);

    return encryptedData;
}
```

But in `decryptWithPrivateKey` I can't able to convert  `uint8_t *plainBuffer` (decrypted result) to `NSString`.First i tried to convert it into `NSData` on printing with `NSLog` it show the bytes properly but then `NSData` is not converting in to string.

```
- (void)decryptWithPrivateKey: (NSData *)dataToDecrypt
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    size_t cipherBufferSize = [dataToDecrypt length];
    uint8_t *cipherBuffer = (uint8_t *)[dataToDecrypt bytes];

    size_t plainBufferSize;
    uint8_t *plainBuffer;

    SecKeyRef privateKey = NULL;

    NSData * privateTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:privateKeyIdentifier
                                         length:strlen((const char *)privateKeyIdentifier)];

    NSMutableDictionary *queryPrivateKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the private key query dictionary.
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:privateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPrivateKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];
    // 1

    status = SecItemCopyMatching
    ((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPrivateKey, (CFTypeRef *)&privateKey); // 2

    //  Allocate the buffer
    plainBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(privateKey);
    plainBuffer = malloc(plainBufferSize);

    if (plainBufferSize < cipherBufferSize) {
        // Ordinarily, you would split the data up into blocks
        // equal to plainBufferSize, with the last block being
        // shorter. For simplicity, this example assumes that
        // the data is short enough to fit.
        printf("Could not decrypt.  Packet too large.\n");
        return;
    }

    //  Error handling

    status = SecKeyDecrypt(    privateKey,
                           kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                           cipherBuffer,
                           cipherBufferSize,
                           plainBuffer,
                           &plainBufferSize
                           );                              // 3

    //*******************************************************************************
    // Not able to convert  uint8_t *plainBuffer to string 
    // I also tried to convert it into NSData and then try to convert it into NSString but can't 
    //What Should i do here to get string back


  if(privateKey) CFRelease(privateKey);
}
@end
```

I want to know how to convert decrypted result `uint8_t plainBuffer` to `NSData` to `NSString` or simply `NSString` so that i get my string back.For my encryption and key generation code please refer this [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can anyone explain why is this question down voted?What is wrong in it

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it. But I can tell you this: Your question doesn't have enough information to figure out your problem. Both I and another user have attempted to get more information out of you, but the only answer you've ever given is "I tried it but it doesn't work"—without explaining what "it" you tried, how you tried it, in what way it failed, etc. So, as it stands, your problem is impossible to debug. But the underlying problem would be easy to debug if you just gave us the information. Which means, as written, this is a bad question.

Comment: I am extremly sorry for that abarnert.Actually I don't have the dump right now but i solved my problem.Actually this example is direct from apple refrence and there is some issue with that.I followed this github [code](https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-Certificate--Key--and-Trust-Sample-Project).Once again thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem by following this  [code](https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-Certificate--Key--and-Trust-Sample-Project).It's the same code but encoding of string is different.In `encryptWithPublicKey` function I have  used

`uint8_t *dataToEncrypt= (uint8_t *)[@"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" UTF8String];`

instead of

`const uint8_t dataToEncrypt[] = "the quick brown fox jumps "
                            "over the lazy dog\0";`

and in `decryptWithPrivateKey` I have used this to decode

```
 NSData *decryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:plainBuffer length:plainBufferSize];
 NSString *decryptedString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 6):

i know this question is old and marked as solved but i got here with a similar problem.
what i found out is that there seems to be an error in the encryption method the apple docs in the line

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:dataLength];
```

datalength is the wrong variable here. i replaced it with cipherbuffersize to

```
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
```

and everythings works well for me now. i hope it is useful for someone else than me.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that you're calling [`+[stringWithCharacters:length:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), which expects Unicode characters (more precisely, UTF-16 code points), but you probably have UTF-8 or another 8-bit encoding.

You have to know which encoding you have, so you can call `+[stringWithCString:encoding:]` (or, if it's UTF-8, `+[stringWithUTF8String:]` for short).

Note that, unlike `stringWithCharacters`, these methods don't take a length, and expect your data to be null-terminated. So, unless you're sure the data will always have a terminator, you should either check for it explicitly, or alloc the string and then call `-[initWithBytes:length:encoding:]`.

If you don't know what charset the plaintext was in before it was encrypted, you need to find out. As a human, you can often tell by looking at it, especially if it's mostly ASCII. Create an `NSData` with the buffer and log that and look at the hex. If it's UTF-16, the ASCII characters will alternate with nulls, so `'Hello'` will be `48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00`. But a computer isn't going to do a very good job guessing. (The reason `+[stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:]` usually gets it right is that it looks at the extended attribute `com.apple.TextEncoding`, which most Cocoa apps write when they save a file.)

Comment: Thanks for response ,i have used so many tricks to convert `plainBuffer` to NSString but cant able to.You can take look of encryption code in **encryptWithPublicKey method**   [refrence]http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13 .if you can give some hint it will be very greatful.

Comment: @SahilWasan: Did you try what I suggested above? Where does the ciphertext come from? What character set was the plaintext in before encryption?

Comment: OK, show a hex dump of your decrypted data (e.g., stick it in an `NSData` and log that).

Comment: @SahilWasan: What does "its not working" mean? What exactly did you try, and what happened? We need a hex dump of your decrypted data to tell you what's wrong with it. (If trying that _also_ gets null, then either your buffer pointer is null or your length is 0, which means you don't have any data to print out.)

Comment: I am upvoting for clearly defining the problem and helped me to solve the problem.Thanks @abarnet for that.I don't have hex dump right now.But i able to solve my problem.